# CDI Interceptor not kicking in

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7

My interceptor is not kicking in when it should, even though it's registered in beans and the files provide no warnings. What am I missing?

**Edit 1:** I want to be able to log each time a function in `Genres.java` is invoked and left, but I am not getting any output at all with this configuration.

**Edit 2:** After following Svetlin's advice to apply breakpoints, I can confirm the code never reaches neither the Interceptor or the Producer.

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <interceptors>
        <class>no.krystah.log.LoggingInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

**LoggingInterceptor.java**

```
package no.krystah.log;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundConstruct;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

@Log @Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @AroundConstruct
    private void init(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Entering constructor");
        try {
            ic.proceed();
        } finally {
            logger.info("Exiting constructor");
        }
    }
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethod(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        logger.info(ic.getTarget().toString()+" - "+ ic.getMethod().getName());
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } finally {
            logger.info(ic.getTarget().toString()+ " - "+ ic.getMethod().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Log.java**

```
package no.krystah.log;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})

public @interface Log {
}
```

**LoggerProducer.java**

```
package no.krystah.log;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@SessionScoped
public class LoggerProducer {   

    @Produces   
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {   
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());   
    }   
}
```

**Genres.java**

```
package no.krystah;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import no.krystah.entity.Genre;
import no.krystah.log.Log;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Log
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Genres {

    public Genres() { }

    /* Functions */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the interceptor is not being invoked ? It's possible that your logger might be set to a higher logging level than what you are logging (for instanace the logger is set to ERROR, but you are logging with level DEBUG -> so as a result nothing will of that will appear in the logs). Please set a breakpoint on the `@AroundInvoke` method and check if it is invoked.

Comment: Hey Svetlin and thanks for your reply. I am logging to the INFO-level, because that worked when I manually created Logger objects and used them; all output reached stdout. And I know how to set breakpoints but I don't know how to "reach" them in a web application.

Comment: You have to run your application in debug mode. Usually this involves a restart of the application server. In eclipse you can right click on your server and click on the "Restart in debug mode" option. Instead of using a breakpoint you can log with ERROR, just to see if the output will reach stdout.But either way it's good to check if the interceptor method is invoked.

Comment: Ok, breakpoints are working but the interceptor is not called. :/

Comment: may you try to inject the logger inside the `Genres` class instead of the interceptor. Also which application server you are using ?

Comment: May I ask where your beans.xml is located? Because java ee 7 is working without one, so a wrong placed beans.xml would lead to the app working without pointing out the error

Comment: The Logger object is injecting properly when done manually. The application server is Wildfly 8. `beans.xml` is located in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.

Comment: Kescha Skywalker is right. You are using the wrong annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the @SessionScoped annotation you are using. The import indicates that you are using

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

Please switch to the CDI one:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
```

Also you shouldn't use @ManagedBean annotation, please replace it through the java ee 7 one:

```
@Named
```